# How to download image from link direct to save or download button click with CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to download an image with CasperJS.
The thing is that I need to download this image from either the click button event or from the direct download link.
I have no code yet, so could anyone help me?

thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `captureSelector()` if you know the specifics of the DOM element you want to capture (class, id, xpath, etc), or `download()` the targeted resourse with it's URI.

You can find the right method for your need in the [Casper Module API Documentation](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html)